# Can not get data from reference field in firebase (flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data via reference field.

My code

```
DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .doc(snapshot.data!.data()!["organisator"]);
                    docRef.get().then((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                      if (document.exists) {
                        print(document.data());
                      }
                    });
```

Print gives me this: `{image: img_url, name: Dan Brown}`

But when I try to get `image` or `name` like this `document.data()!["image"]` I always get an error:

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining
> the operator '[]'.

I saw possible solution with `document.data.data()` but it returns me just an error.

So how can I actually get `name` or `image` properties from my response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the data to a map like this

```
document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>
```

Comment: Hi @Nathaniel
Thank you for your answer.
`document.data.data()` returns me this error: `The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Function'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'`

Comment: it should be document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>. I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who will face same problem, this is my working code, based on Nathaniel Akubuo answer.

```
DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .doc(snapshot.data!.data()!["organisator"]);
                    docRef.get().then((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                      if (document.exists) {
                        Map<String, dynamic> finData =
                            document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                        print(finData["name"]); //Dan Brown output
                      }
                    });
```

As a result of print I successfully get the needed `name` value.